# Proof the sum of the square of the in and out degree are the same

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I know by the handshaking theorem that in a graph, the sum of the in degree and the sum of the out degree will be the same. I observe that in a complete directed graph (as in a complete graph that has directions assigned to each edge), the sum of the squares of the in degree and the sum of the squares of the out degree are the same as well.

At first, I thought it was because a 2 in the in degree would match up with a 2 in the out degree, but that's not the case.

I've been playing around with this for a few hours but I can't figure out why it's true. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: btw, the more standard name for a complete directed graph is a tournament graph.

Comment: "complete directed graph" should probably be "oriented complete graph" or just "tournament graph".  The term "complete directed graph" suggests arcs in all possible directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each vertex $v_i$, where $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$, let $x_i$ be the out-degree of $v_i$ and $y_i$ be the in-degree of $v_i$.

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i^2-y_i^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i+y_i)(x_i-y_i)$. Because the graph is complete, $x_i+y_i$ is a constant, namely $n-1$. Thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i^2-y_i^2)=(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i).$$
But as you mentioned, the sum of the in-degrees is the same as the sum of the out-degrees, so $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-y_i)=0$.

**Remark:** I prefer the following version. During the season, each team in the NBA played the same number of games. Let $W_i$ be the number of games Team $i$ won, and $L_i$ be the number of games it lost (there are no ties in basketball). Show that $\sum W_i^2=\sum L_i^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand now. Sorry for the duplicate.

Comment: I didn't know it was a duplicate either, by this time on MSE the majority of questions are duplicates or near duplicates.  But *finding* is not easy.